# How to check the root node value when parsing with XML Dom Parser ?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom

I have One XML file which will be look like this ::

```
<Note>
     <NoteId>13328</NoteId>
     <NoteTitle>hiiiii</NoteTitle>
     <NoteDescription>Hi</NoteDescription>
</Note>
```

I am successfully parse this kind of XML.My Problem is that when i fired the webservice and if there is no authentication from the server then the webservice response like this::

```
<AuthenticationError>An Active Session Already Exists For This User.</AuthenticationError>
```

So how can i check that root node is "Authentication Error" or "Notes".
And if i get the Authentication Error tag then how can i get its node value which is "An Active Session Already Exists For This User."??

My Code for XML Parsing is this::

```
     Element node=null;

node = (Element)result.getElementsByTagName("Notes").item(0);
websiteList = node.getElementsByTagName("Note");

for(int j=0;j<websiteList.getLength();j++)
{                               
    Element checkNode=(Element)websiteList.item(j);
    MessagesInbox msg_inbox=new MessagesInbox();

    msg_inbox.note_id = getValueFromNode(checkNode,"NoteId");
    msg_inbox.note_title = getValueFromNode(checkNode,"NoteTitle");
    msg_inbox.note_description = getValueFromNode(checkNode,"NoteDescription");


    arr_msg_inbox_list.add(msg_inbox);
}
```

I hope my question is clear... 
Please provide the solution asap.
Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get root node reference via calling this method - `document.getDocumentElement()`.

```
Element root=document.getDocumentElement();
if(root.getNodeName().equals("AuthenticationError")){
  //get text content 
   String str=root.getTextContent();
}else{
  //
}
```

Comment: What do you mean **where**? Is this your question or not? You want to compare root node name and value. Isn't it? I don't know what is the name of `Document` ref variable so I've used `document`. (May be you can use `result` if it is `Document` type).

Comment: How do i get string value of Authentication Error Tag??